# Set curator of split in case of the 17 June 2016 attack

Tags: the-dao, dao, attacks

When creating a proposal for a split, the `recipient` is the new curator.

`splitDAO()` has 2 arguments :

- proposalID: The proposal ID.
- newCurator: The address of the new Curator of
  the new DAO.

As I understand, anyone can join an existing split, and then call the `splitDAO()` function with himself as newCurator.

The questions are :

- If I set myself as the curator in the proposal, others people who wanted to join the split will also have to call `splitDAO()` with the same curator address, or another one ?
- Vitalik said they are in touch with the proposal #59 curator, so the attacker did not split with himself as curator ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this line of the contract's source code, https://github.com/slockit/DAO/blob/develop/DAO.sol#L631, the curator specified in `splitDAO()` has to be the same as specified in the proposal, so the attacker is stuck if he isn't the curator of the proposal.